# Como marcar check numa coluna DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn em VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Vi que tem bastante material sobre como verificar se o check está marcado ou não, mas não estou conseguindo marcar a caixa do objeto dentro do DataGrid. ao clicar na DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn ela não marca. Alguém pode ajudar ?

Comment: Coloque os trechos do seu código para saber no que podemos ajudar

Comment: @EduardoOliveira eu criei o dataGrid e quero adicionar uma coluna DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn para marcar a linha inteira. Fiz quase tudo via Design msm, inclusive adicionar as colunas. O problema é que ao rodar o programa não dá pra marcar o Check. Sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a que melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ideia é você criar um método para verificar a mudança de estado.

```
      Private Sub dgv_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellContentClick
            // vê se a culuna clicada é a que tem o checkbox
          If dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
            // vê se a linha está marcada true
             If dgv.Item(0, dgv.CurrentRow.Index).Value() Then
                dgv.Item(0, dgv.CurrentRow.Index).Value() = False
             Else
                dgv.Item(0, dgv.CurrentRow.Index).Value() = True
             End If
          End If
       End Sub
```

Talvez lhe atenda esse tipo de verificação.

Comment: então eu preciso de um método só para dar check no componente? ou se eu clicar nele ele deva marcar/desmarcar e então faço a verificação?

Comment: A ideia é usar CellContentClick e pegar o evento do click no seu grid. Pegando esse evento, você deve verificar se o click foi na coluna onde está o seu checkbox. Caso o seu checkbox esteja marcado você então desmarca e o contrario também se aplica.

Comment: Consegui entender e seu exemplo foi muito útil. ;)